# Show detail for nested object while also prepopulating update form

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a foreign key to my User table, I'd like to include the user as nested json, and I'd like the HTML template update form to be prepopulated, all without duplicating the user in my json output.

If I add the user as a `write_only` `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, the user doesn't get prepopulated in my update form's dropdown. Without `write_only`, the user also shows up in my output json like `"user": 1`.

Is there a way to get the user in the json once, as a json object, and also get my updated dropdown populated?

Comment: Can you please share the serializer with the relevant parts (you don't have to include non-relevant items) together with the view(set)?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I had `user = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(write_only=True)` and `user_detail=UserSerializer(source='user', read_only=True)`, with both `user` and `user_detail` in my serializer's `fields`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up splitting up my parent model's serializers, so I have one serializer with `user = UserSerializer()`, another with `user = PrimaryKeyRelatedField()`, and I switch between these serializers in my viewset's `get_serializer` method, depending on the value of `self.action` (`'update'` vs. `'retrieve'`).

Here's a little code to hopefully illustrate:

```
class OrganizationInviteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
        if self.action in ['create', 'update']:
            return OrganizationInviteStoreSerializer(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return OrganizationInviteDetailSerializer(*args, **kwargs)

    ...

class OrganizationInviteDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    ...

class OrganizationInviteStoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
    ...
```

(With "*...*" representing additional irrelevant code).

Answer (score -1):

just use one serializer for get/post/update/delete queries

try this

**Serializers as s**

User

```
class UserSerializer(s.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = m.User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'is_staff',
            # your fields
        ]
```

Payment # for exemple

```
class PaymentSerializer(s.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True) # only for get
    user_id= s.IntegerField(write_only=True) # only for post/patch/put/delete

    class Meta:
        model = m.Payment
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Viewsets**

```
class PaymentViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    CRUD endpoint for model Payment
    """
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = models.Payment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.PaymentSerializer
    renderer_classes = [renderers.JSONRenderer]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't populate the HTML template dropdowns for updates; more detail: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/1699